# Hibernate configuration troubles

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic

Trying hibernate & doing as manuals say. But it doesn't work.

```
package util;

//imports

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    static {
        try {
            System.out.println("HU 01");
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            System.out.println("HU 02");
            configuration.configure();
            System.out.println("HU 03");
                //creates the session factory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();   
            System.out.println("HU 04");     
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            System.out.println("HU 05");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HU 06");
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        System.out.println("HU 00");
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I've got next logs (placed System.out... everywhere):

```
Main class starts.
Factory initialised.
Factory.Entity initialised.
ImplDAO 1
HU 01
ImplDAO 8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:176)
    at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    at dao.impl.ImplDAO.setData(ImplDAO.java:27)
    at service.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)
```

"HU 01" appears in console, "HU 02" doesn't. So, I think, I have got some hibernate.cfg.xml problems, but it's also made with manual:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1251:XE</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <mapping class="logic.EntityClass" />

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My environement:

```
Hibernate 4.1
WebLogic Server 11gR1
Oracle DataBase 11g Express Edition
Eclipse Juno
JRE: jdk1.7.0_09
    (same thing with Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.2) JRE)
```

AnyIdea?

Comment: As the exception suggests, do you have the required libraries (containing `org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger`) on your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Hibernate configuration problem. Your are missing a dependency : jboss-logging.jar. That's why your program cannot find the class org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger

Comment: Hm, I thought I didn't need jboss jars if I use WebLogic. With jboss-jar, i have a new trouble. Thanks for this step.

Comment: It's an Hibernate dependency

Answer (score 1):

You're missing out one or more of the dependencies. This is how the dependency hierarchy looks like for one of my projects:

[image]

Make sure you have the required jars in the classpath of your application. If possible use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It does the dependency management for you, among a lot other things.

Comment: Thanks. Hoped not to study maven, but "Tutte vie conducano a Roma."

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to suggest maven to solve just this one problem. Of course priority here should be to find one solution which solves the problem quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

you need jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA which comes with hibernate distribution or it can downloaded seperately.